# Jquery, not sure why animate height doesn't work as expected

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the following code to work.

When user scrolls to point x the menu wrapper reduces in height.  They can reinstate the height by clicking .extender.  After clicking this link, the link disappears (so there is no toggle functionality).

I see that toggle tends to be a solution in similar use cases, I'd ideally like to know how to solve this problem, and why the code I have doesn't work.

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    var height = $('div#zone-menu-wrapper').height();
    if (some_logic){
        $('div#zone-branding-wrapper').animate({height: 10}, 1500);
    }
});

$('.extender').click(function(){
    $('div#zone-branding-wrapper').animate({height: 380}, 1500);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: You've given a good explanation of what your code does. What's the problem?

Comment: You should use jquery stop before animation. because scroll will for for each pixel change

Comment: hi, the problem is that when i click the extender the height animation does not trigger and it remains the same height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

return if animation is already in progress.

```
 var inProgress = false;
$(document).scroll(function(){
    if(inProgress )return;
    var height = $('div#zone-menu-wrapper').height();
    if (some_logic){
      inProgress = true;
        $('div#zone-branding-wrapper').animate({height: 10}, 1500, function(){
                  inProgress = false;
        });
    }
});

$('.extender').click(function(){
    $('div#zone-branding-wrapper').animate({height: 380}, 1500);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I slightly modified your answer so animate height was only called once.  I think the problem was that it was called more than once but your answer put me on to that so you get the points.